# change color Highcharts Map

Tags: javascript

Hello everything is fine? I'm learning a little js here on the force because of a job. I'm using a library to generate a map of the northeast region of Brazil and I even managed to get the result I need, however, I couldn't find where I change the blue color of the map. I need to put a #F8AB85 in the background, leave it with a white border and a transparent background. It's possible?

I also tried using https://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/create-custom-maps but it didn't work either.

https://jsfiddle.net/tikovolpe/L83nb97f/3/

My js code is the one below, I tried adding fill but it had no effect.

```
(async () => {

  const topology = await fetch(
      'js/nordeste.topo.json'
  ).then(response => response.json());

  // Prepare demo data. The data is joined to map using value of 'hc-key'
  // property by default. See API docs for 'joinBy' for more info on linking
  // data and map.
  const data = [
      ['br-ma', ],
      ['br-ba', 0],
      ['br-pi', 8,49],
      ['br-al', 8,50],
      ['br-pb', 7,79],
      ['br-ce', 8,09],
      ['br-se', 8,36],
      ['br-pe', 8,47],
      ['br-rn', 8,34],
  ];

  // Create the chart
  Highcharts.mapChart('mapa-nordeste', {
      chart: {
          map: topology
      },

      title: {
          text: 'A MELHOR OPERADORA DE BANDA LARGA FIXA'
      },

      mapNavigation: {
          enabled: false,
          buttonOptions: {
              verticalAlign: 'bottom'
          }
      },

      colorAxis: {
          min: 0
      },

      series: [{
          data: data,
          name: 'Random data',
          states: {
            fill: ('#F8AB85'),
              hover: {
                  color: '#E9501F'
              }
          },
          dataLabels: {
              enabled: true,
              format: '{point.name}'
          }
      }]
  });

})();
```